# Excel deletes cell content of cells I try to edit in a protected work sheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, cells

I have "inherited" an excel workbook I need to fix and the original creator has - of course - gone years before I received the task that I have to fix this file.

The sheets of the file are all protected (I have the password to unlock them luckily), a few cells however are not protected and they can be edited, this is intentional.

**My problem however:** The creator somehow managed to inlucde a setting in which the content of an editable cell is completely deleted if you want to edit it. This does only happen when the sheet which contains this cell is protected. I tried out if this behaviour occurs also in a fresh new workbook but it doesn't.

I hope this illustration clarifies what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the cell in question. Then, click Format Cell, go to the Protection tab, and deselect the "Hidden" option.